# Rake in Ruby: undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm currently trying to run a Rake task in a Ruby project (No Rails). What I am trying to accomplish is to run a method from a file within my Ruby project. However I get the following error:

```
undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I created a folder `task` that holds a `test.rb` file. Before I had it as `test.rake` but I think this was incorrect. I also created a `Rakefile` pointing to `task/test.rb`
[image]

For redeability, I'm using `namespace:` although I'll be honest I'm not sure if I even need it.

```
#Rakefile
task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  ruby 'task/test.rb'
end
```

Here is the `task.test.rb`

```
require './src/lambda_function.rb'

class KMS
    def initialize
    end

    def decrypt(key)
       return "some password"
    end
end

class SNS
    def initialize
    end
end

TEST_FORM_ID=123

namespace :test do
  namespace :lambda do
    desc 'Run the Lambda process function'
    task :process  do
      LambdaFunctions::LambdaHandler.process(box_api: BoxApi.new,
                                             form: TEST_FORM_ID,
                                             sns: SNS.new,
                                             kms: KMS.new)
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You call `namespace` which is a rake method in a pure Ruby file but `namespace` is not defined in Ruby, therefore you get the error message. It is not clear to me what you try to achieve by defining a rake task in a Ruby file. You can probably just call  `LambdaFunctions::LambdaHandler.process` directly in that file without nesting it into rake namespace and task definitions.

Comment: @spickermann The reason to use Rake is to improving testing the application process. Currently, to test it I have to comment out two client files and then running the file `lambda_function.rb`to run the process